# Use 'DateDiff' function in a 'Custom Column'

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to create a custom column in PowerBI which calculates the number of days between `Date` column and today. So I follow the example from [https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/power-bi-date-difference/#:~:text=To%20find%20the%20difference%20between%20the%20date%20from,measure%20%3ADiff%20%3D%20DATEDIFF%20%28Table1%20%5BDate%5D%2C%20TODAY%20%28%29%2CDAY%29](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/power-bi-date-difference/#:%7E:text=To%20find%20the%20difference%20between%20the%20date%20from,measure%20%3ADiff%20%3D%20DATEDIFF%20%28Table1%20%5BDate%5D%2C%20TODAY%20%28%29%2CDAY%29) and do

`= Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each DateDiff([Date], Today(), Day))`

But I get error saying `Expression.Error: The name 'DateDiff' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly`

My guess is I can't use `DAX` function in the 'Custom column formula` . But when I look at the available formula from the popup. I can't find one which calculates the number of days between 2 columns.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't use DAX. Power Query uses [M formula language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/). There you can use [Duration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/duration-functions) to calculate a duration, and more specific [Duration.Days](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/duration-days) in your case. Get the current date and time using for example [DateTimeZone.UtcNow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/datetimezone-utcnow) (working with UTC is recommended to avoid some unexpected results when publishing your report to the service for example) and convert that to a date using [DateTime.Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/datetime-date). So the code for the custom column could be something like this:

```
Duration.Days(DateTime.Date(DateTimeZone.UtcNow()) - [Date])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are in PowerQuery.

```
Duration.Days(Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())-Date.From([Date Column]))
```

Comment: Hi @n179911a : did you solve your question?

Comment: Edit: I accidentally deleted this just now when I tried to copy it: for some reading about DAX vs PowerQuery … https://radacad.com/m-or-dax-that-is-the-question